# Move files to one folder per filetype

Tags: windows, file-management, hard-disk

**Background**

I have a collection of many different backups over the years in 3 different hard drive and a myriad of folders in each (100s). Some of them are many multiple incremental backups. A few years back I bought Duplicate Cleaner Pro 4 to take on the project but it's been daunting. Someone somewhere suggested first I should consolidate all the data into one place and create folders by file type and move each occurrence of file type into their own folder - which I thought an excellent suggestion. Last year I bought a 4TB drive which will allow for such consolidation. Then I can use Duplicate Cleaner from there.

**Objective**

What I am looking for is software that given many tree branches will go through all subfolders and completely reorganise the files, moving all files of the same type to a folder. I am looking for software that would do this / allow rules to be written in to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) for that.

Despite the name, it can move, rename and copy as method of action.

Another option (more techy) is sharing the folders with an virtual Linux machine and make an script - it's really easy to do so with the `file` utility.